# gtkbutton font color change

Tags: linux, gtk

I am trying to change the color of text displayed on GtkButton using gtk_widget_modify_fg() but it is not working. I have successfully changed the background of GtkButton using gtk_widget_modify_bg() but foreground one is not working.

Please help.

Regards
-Durgesh O Mishra

Answer (score 1):

you can get GtkLabel child widget of your button using gtk_bin_get_child, then you should be able to change its foreground color with gtk_widget_modify_fg as you initially planned

example (python) can be found here: [How to set a Gtk2::Button's text colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258963/how-to-set-a-gtk2buttons-text-colour/7369328#7369328)

Answer (score 0):

You could put a `GtkLabel` widget inside the button and colour that. Keep in mind that users like programs that stay consistent with the system theme.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this trouble too.
I'm using Mono Gtk#.
It turns out each time you change the button text it creates a new child Label widget to display the text.
You have to change the foreground color for the child widget each time you change the text.

```
    private void ChangeButtonTextAndColor (Button button, string text)
    {
        // Get forground color of the button widget to use for the label text color
        var fore = button.Style.Foreground (StateType.Normal);

        // Change the text - it will create a new label widget
        // Note:  Child will be NULL until some text is set
        button.Label = text;

        // Change the text color for the new label
        // One color for all the different states
        button.Child.ModifyFg (StateType.Insensitive, fore);
        button.Child.ModifyFg (StateType.Active, fore);
        button.Child.ModifyFg (StateType.Normal, fore);
        button.Child.ModifyFg (StateType.Prelight, fore);
        button.Child.ModifyFg (StateType.Selected, fore);
    }
```