# How to set a Gtk2::Button's text colour?

Tags: perl, colors, gtk

I am trying to set a colour to highlight a button. However, the modify_fg method only seems to set the focus ring's colour. modify_bg works as expected.

This is my code:

```
use Gtk2 qw/-init/;

my $window = Gtk2::Window->new;
$window->set_title("Window!");

my $button = Gtk2::Button->new("Coloured _button");
# does not affect text
$button->modify_fg(normal => Gtk2::Gdk::Color->new(0xffff, 0, 0));

$window->add($button);
$window->show_all;

Gtk2->main;
```

I'm also interested whether there is a standard colour for this sort of highlight, to blend in with the user's theme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change background color of GtkTextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770558/how-to-change-background-color-of-gtktextview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can get the button's child label and modify its foreground, below is an example (python, let me know if there are troubles converting it to perl)

```
import gtk        

class TestWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

        box = gtk.VBox()

        button0 = gtk.Button("Test Button")
        label0 = button0.get_children()[0]
        label0.modify_fg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse('red'))

        button1 = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_ABOUT)
        alignment = button1.get_children()[0]
        hbox = alignment.get_children()[0]
        image, label1 = hbox.get_children()
        label1.modify_fg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL, gtk.gdk.color_parse('blue'))

        box.add(button0)
        box.add(button1)

        window.add(box)
        window.set_size_request(200, 200)
        window.show_all()        

    def close_application(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestWindow()
    gtk.main()
```

hope this helps, regards

Answer (score 1):

All previous helped a lot...

All the following works ok!

```
my $beige = Gtk2::Gdk::Color->new (0xFFFF,0xFFFF,0xCCCC);
my $azul  = Gtk2::Gdk::Color->new (0,0,0xCCCC);
my $rojo  = Gtk2::Gdk::Color->new (0xCCCC,0,0);

$mw->modify_bg ("normal", $beige);

my $butOk = Gtk2::Button->new_with_label("  ¡Ya Terminé!");
($butOk->get_children)[0]->modify_fg("normal", $azul);
($butOk->get_children)[0]->modify_font(Pango::FontDescription->from_string ("Serif Bold 27"));
my $imgBTN = Gtk2::Button->new();
my $img    = Gtk2::Image->new_from_file("$imagen");
$imgBTN->set_property("image"=>$img);
```